# RAML dependent required query parameters

Tags: raml

I have the following trait:

```
traits:
  feedSortable:
    queryParameters:
      sortBy:
        description:  Sort the topic feed
        required:     false
        default:      'created_at'
        type:         string
        enum:         [ 'most_recent', 'upvotes' ]

      since:
        description:  Get topics since utc creation date. Required in case of upvotes
        required:     false
        type:         datetime-only

      until:
        description:  Get topics until utc creation date
        required:     false
        type:         datetime-only
```

`Since` and `until` query parameters are only required when `sortBy` is defined as `upvotes`.
How do I enforce this best in my RAML definition?

More generally, I want to know how I define query parameter definitions dependent on other query parameters. Can't be that rare?

Comment: Did you try using `queryString` instead of `queryParameter`?  Along with Union types it should be possible to get specced.  Here's the documentation: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#the-query-string-as-a-whole

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a good way although this would seem to be a case that is relatively common. Swagger seems too restrictive, RAML seems to be missing options too.

I circumvented the issue by making the field non-required altogether, and adding more description to the default:

```
  since:
    description:  Get topics since utc creation date
    required:     false
    default:      sortBy = recent -> null, sortBy = upvotes -> now() - 1 month
    type:         datetime-only
```